# Different height for multiple prototype cells

Tags: swift, uitableview, height, cell

Have 2 prototype cells. Each need to be a different size.So I have cell and cell1. Cell should be 40 and Cell needs to be 75.

I tried using heightForRowAt - Found out that that is called before cellForRowAt

I tired setting the height in the story board, for each cell

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "starshipCell", for: indexPath)
       let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "starshipCell1", for: indexPath) as! SectionTableViewCell

       switch indexPath {
       case [4,0]:
           cell1.sectionLbl.text = "Armor".lowercased()
           cell1.detailTextLabel?.text = "Test"
           return cell1
       case [4,1]:
           cell.textLabel?.text = "Defensive Countermeasures"
           return cell
       case [4,2]:
           cell.textLabel?.text = "Shields"
           return cell
       case [11, 0]:
           cell.textLabel?.text = "Forward Arc"
           return cell
       case [11, 1]:
           cell.textLabel?.text = "Port Arc"
           return cell
       case [11, 2]:
           cell.textLabel?.text = "Starboard Arc"
           return cell
       case [11, 3]:
           cell.textLabel?.text = "Aft Arc"
           return cell
       case [11, 4]:
           cell.textLabel?.text = "Turret"
           return cell
       default:
           return cell
       }

      // return cell
   }
```

'Attempted to dequeue multiple cells for the same index path, which is not allowed. If you really need to dequeue more cells than the table view is requesting, use the -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method (without an index path). Cell identifier: starshipCell1, index path:  {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'

So the above works perfectly. I just need to adjust the row height for those cells. Now the code isn't 100% complete. All the cases above will be changed and updated to cell1. The error is only when I use heightForRowAt

Comment: Are you using autolayout in both prototype cells?

Comment: I haven't added it yet. I just discovered I could have multiple prototype cells. So I was testing a concept out. Now I have notice that in story board if I change the height of the cell itself then it does't change it when I build it. But if I select the table and change the row height it applies the desired height. The problem here is I need to different heights.

Comment: You can use autolayout in both prototype cells. And use UITableView.automaticDimension in heightForRow method. You'll get 2 cells with different heights. Check this http://www.thomashanning.com/uitableview-automatic-row-height/

Comment: That tutorial didn't help. I don't have text that will push to a second line.

Comment: When do you want to use cell and when cell1?

Comment: All the time. It will show a default selection then the user selects a cell and is then taken to a secondary view where they select an option. Then it goes back to the first view and displays the selection.

Answer (score 0):

Within the `cellForRowAt` method, you can only dequeue and return one cell. To return the right one given the index path, common practice is something more like the following:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell
    if indexPath.row == 0 { // starshipCell only appears if it's the first row
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "starshipCell", for: indexPath)
    } else { // Otherwise, we use starshipCell1
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "starshipCell1", for: indexPath) as! SectionTableViewCell
    }

    // Set up the cell here

    return cell
}
```

This way, dequeueReusableCell is only called once per cell. (the error) `heightForRowAt` should be used similarly.

Comment: Updated with the full cellForRowAt

Comment: The problem is still there, though. You can't call dequeueReusableCell and then call it again on the next line. You have to decide, based on the row number, what cell type it's going to be and stick to it from that point of execution going forward. Judging from your existing code, I have a feeling your heightForRowAt is already laid out correctly.

Comment: I will tell you this again that the above works exactly as I need it. I have 2 different prototype cells. Each cell has its own identifier and the above listed indexPath's use the second reuse. The only thing I can get to work with the height change is when I have the table selected. I then change the row height and it changes for both cells. If I change the height of the cell it still continues to be the default height.